# De Broglie's justification for the quantisation of electorn orbit radius

Tags: atomic-physics, atoms

I am reading about De Broglie and how his particle wave duality explained the fact that electrons can only exist in specific, quantised, energies/ranges from the nucleus, but I can't understand why. Everything I have come across follows this logic,
[http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/c37_deBroglie.html](http://physics.bu.edu/%7Eduffy/semester2/c37_deBroglie.html), where they claim that you must have an integer amount of wavelengths or else the electron will have destructive interference with itself.

But, what this proves is that **m*v*r**  is quantised (or **m*p** in some cases).

Why can't the electron move in r/2, meaning half the current "minimum" radius and have double the velocity? That would result in having half the wavelength λ form the current state and thus an integral number of wavelengths fit in the circumference of an orbit, just like before. I use half as an example but it stands for all numbers.

Comment: Centripetal force has to be equal to the Coulomb force. This forbids such tuning of radius and velocity.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the reason, I was focused on the wave behavior I forgot that the particle one still applies , thanks

Answer (score 1):

De Broglie hypothesis consists in saying that the electron is associated with a wave length given by:

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$$

On the other hand, the fitting of the wave to a circular orbit requires:

$$n\lambda = 2\pi r, \qquad n\in \mathbb{N}^*$$

using both equations, we get:

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{mv} = \frac{2\pi r}{n} \quad \Rightarrow mvr = \frac{h}{2\pi} = \hbar$$